# Multiple Jquery Slideshows

Tags: jquery, slideshow, cycle

I am trying to create a page with multiple jquery slideshows each with their own next, previous button using jquery cycle all. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx:'fade', 
    speed:1, 
    timeout: 0, 
    next:'#next',
    prev:'#prev',
    });
});

    </script>
```

and the html for 2 slideshows (but i want 4)

```
<div id="content">
<a name="1" id="1"></a>
<div id ="slideshow">
  <img src="image2.jpg" width="675" height="420" />
  <img src="image.jpg" width="675" height="420" />
</div>
<a id="prev" href="#" class="Code-Pro3">Prev</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;  <a id="next" href="#" class="Code-Pro3">Next </a>


<a name="2" id="2"></a>
<div id ="slideshow2">
  <img src="image.jpg" width="675" height="420" />
  <img src="image2.jpg" width="675" height="420" />
</div>
<a id="prev" href="#" class="Code-Pro3">Prev</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;  <a id="next" href="#" class="Code-Pro3">Next </a>
```

any help is appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have two separate divs with their own previous and next links, you'll need to call cycle twice and use unique ids for the links. So your script should look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#slideshow1').cycle({
    fx:'fade', 
    speed:1, 
    timeout: 0, 
    next:'#next1',
    prev:'#prev1',
    });
$('#slideshow2').cycle({
    fx:'fade', 
    speed:1, 
    timeout: 0, 
    next:'#next2',
    prev:'#prev2',
    });
});

</script>
```

and your markup looks like:

```
<div id="content">
<a name="1" id="1"></a>
<div id ="slideshow1">
  <img src="image2.jpg" width="675" height="420" />
  <img src="image.jpg" width="675" height="420" />
</div>
<a id="prev1" href="#" class="Code-Pro3">Prev</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;  <a id="next1" href="#" class="Code-Pro3">Next </a>

<a name="2" id="2"></a>
<div id ="slideshow2">
  <img src="image.jpg" width="675" height="420" />
  <img src="image2.jpg" width="675" height="420" />
</div>
<a id="prev2" href="#" class="Code-Pro3">Prev</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;  <a id="next2" href="#" class="Code-Pro3">Next </a>
```

See http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/scrollhv.html for an example.

Hope that helps,

David

Answer (score 0):

One way of telling each `.slideshow` on a page to find its own *prev* and *next* buttons is to group the slideshow and the *prev* and *next* button in the same parent and then find them with jQuery selectors:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').each(function(){
      $(this).cycle({
        fx:'fade', 
        speed:1, 
        timeout: 0,
        next: $('.next', $(this).parent()),
        prev: $('.prev', $(this).parent())
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

and now in the html, you can use classes rather than ids, just don't forget to group each slideshow with its own *prev* and *next* buttons.

```
<div id="content">
  <div>
    <a name="1" id="1"></a>
    <div class ="slideshow">
      <img src="image2.jpg" width="675" height="420" />
      <img src="image.jpg" width="675" height="420" />
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="Code-Pro3 prev">Prev</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;  <a href="#" class="Code-Pro3 next">Next </a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a name="2" id="2"></a>
    <div class ="slideshow">
      <img src="image.jpg" width="675" height="420" />
      <img src="image2.jpg" width="675" height="420" />
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="Code-Pro3 prev">Prev</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;  <a href="#" class="Code-Pro3 next">Next </a>
  </div>
  ...
```